# Kitty Terminal Launch directory location?

Tags: kitty

I switched from iTerm to Kitty.

In iterm I could set the starting location for new terminal windows to the desktop.

Which config option is this in kitty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a startup session file: [see details here](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/overview/#sessions).

If all you want to do is start in a certain folder, the file could be named `~/.config/kitty/kitty-startup.session` and consist of one line:

```
cd /path/where/I/want/to/start
```

If you want to make that session the default, in your `kitty.conf` put:

```
startup_session ~/.config/kitty/kitty-startup.session
```

You can have multiple session files and load whichever one you want with:

```
kitty --session /path/to/session/file
```

Though if all you want to do is start in a new folder, you can just give the folder name as argument as well:

```
kitty /path/to/folder
```